# show image on imageview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll, plist

i have one problem. i need to get the images from plist and show it on the imageview? my plist structure is (category)array--> sub category(dictionary) which can be more than one--> images (array) and scroll in horizontally. please suggest some answer as soon as possible.

Comment: :D .... are you saving the images name in the plist? I think so....

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)getImage
{
NSArray *imageArray = [NSarray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
for(NSDictionary *dict in imageArray)
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:imageKey]];
}
}
```

Comment: What are the contetns of your plist? Arent those dictionaries with image names

Comment: its description and then image name

Comment: then use `[dict objectForKey:keyForName];`